# Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax.

Tags: gmail-api

Hi I am having a problem between invoking to many times and then too much execution time.

So if I add the Utilities Sleep 1000 in as suggested then my program takes too long to run and I get the execution time out.

My script reads my contacts and 1000 or so of them and then looks to see what the date was that I last sent each of the and email.

Shar

Comment: Can you write some code or pseudo code to show what methods you're calling?  Are you talking about the Gmail REST API or something else (e.g. Apps Scripts)?

Answer (score 0):

I get my contacts, contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(),  I then parse the emails out (var emails = contacts[c].getEmails()),   then I build a query and search for some mesages var conversations = GmailApp.search(query).  lastly I parse those message messages = conversations[i].getMessages().

I have commented out 90% of the code and still go between too much time and to many calls.  So if I reduce the sleep time it complains about one if I increase the time it complains about the other.

I created a second email account with about 10 contacts and 50 emails and was able to get the code to run.  When I got the contacts to greater that 60 the problems started.

I think that it is awesome that the api's are available but the limits that they have created make them pretty hard to use for any larger data sets.